# How do I change the picture that appears inside the app page

Tags: sharepoint-online

How do I change this picture? It appears when I run my app.

[image]

Comment: That is the site logo, it can be changed in the UI, your app is probably just inheriting the site default. You can replace it with a css override.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with css than. thnx!